# Saturate a level plot to increase contrast at lower levels

Tags: r, plot, heatmap, lattice, levelplot

Given a data set that looks like this:

```
D<-rep(seq(1,5),10)
T<-runif(50,1,20)
S<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10)
DF<-data.frame(D,T,S)
```

I make a level plot using the below code

```
library(lattice)
levelplot(T ~ S * D, data = DF,ylim=c(5,1),
xlab = "T", ylab = "S",
main = "LevelPlot", aspect=0.4,
col.regions =colorRampPalette(c('blue','red')),at=seq(0,20, length.out=120))
```

I want to focus on the subtle differences at the lower end of the data (The T variable) by increasing the contrast in colors. One way I've been able to do this is to change the "seq" argument to focus on data in the range of 0-5:

```
levelplot(T ~ S * D, data = DF,ylim=c(5,1),
xlab = "T", ylab = "S",
main = "LevelPlot", aspect=0.4,
col.regions =colorRampPalette(c('blue','red')),at=seq(0,5, length.out=120))
```

Now the contrast is where I want it to be, but I don't like that all data between 5-20 is blocked out. In other plotting programs I've been able to saturate the upper range so that all data above a certain value is represented by a single (max) color. In this case, all values above 5 would be red (and the color scale on the right would reflect this). Allowing for a more detailed contrast in color scale for values 0-5.

How is this possible to do in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `colorkey` and `at` to do this:

```
my.brks <- seq(0, max(T), by = 3)
my.at <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, round(max(T), 0))
myColorkey <- list(at = my.brks, labels = list(at = my.brks, labels = my.at))

levelplot(
  T ~ S * D,
  data = DF,
  ylim = c(5, 1),
  xlab = "T",
  ylab = "S",
  aspect = 0.4,
  at = my.at,
  col.regions = colorRampPalette(c('blue', 'red')),
  colorkey = myColorkey
)
```

[image]

```
library(latticeExtra)
levelplot(
  T ~ S * D,
  data = DF,
  ylim = c(5, 1),
  xlab = "T",
  ylab = "S",
  aspect = 0.4,
  at = my.at,
  col.regions = colorRampPalette(c('blue', 'red')),
  colorkey = myColorkey
) + layer(panel.text(S, D, round(T, 1)), data = DF)
```

[image]

Comment: This only seems to change the  color bar, but not the actual plot. So I can't see the emphasis on the lower numbers in the actual plot. If I include the line "col.regions =colorRampPalette(c('blue','red')),at=seq(0,20, length.out=120))" I still see the blank areas on the plot. My goal would be to have the same plot, but with all the areas that are now blank be the same max color of red)

Comment: You are right. Forgot to specify the `at` parameter. I updated my answer.